# Experience gain in Enklave

Tags: enklave

How much experience do you get for certain actions in augmented reality game **Enklave**?

Comment: What is the tag [tag:arg]?

Comment: @SaintWacko Damn, I totally forgot to write a description. It's `Augmented Reality Game`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By simply comparing the XP values before and after actions, it is obvious that you get:

- **20** for building a block on an Enclave
- **290** for building the *very first* block on a neutral Enclave

The xp gain for each hit during fighting (attack/defend) is uncertain to me at the moment.